# Characterize set of matrices that are orthogonal in two particular senses

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, orthogonality, matrix-decomposition, quantum-information

Does there exist an analytical characterization of the set of matrices $\Gamma_k\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ such that both

$$
\sum_{k=1}^K\Gamma_k^T\Lambda_0\Gamma_k=I
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k=1}^K\Gamma_k\Lambda_1\Gamma_k^T=I
$$
hold, for a particular choice of real diagonal matrices $\Lambda_i$ and $I$ being the identity matrix?

For $\Lambda_0=I$, the first condition holds if
$$
U_0=\begin{pmatrix} \Gamma_1 \\ \vdots\\ \Gamma_K\end{pmatrix}
$$
is a column-orthogonal matrix, and similarly, the second condition holds for $\Lambda_1=I$ if 
$$
U_1=\begin{pmatrix} \Gamma_1^T \\ \vdots\\ \Gamma_K^T\end{pmatrix}
$$
is column-orthogonal.

For context, this is of interest when constructing canonical representations of so-called matrix product states.

Comment: I think you're more likely to get some answers if you give special examples of values for $\Lambda_0$ and $\Lambda_1$ that you might use.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy I am frankly interested in joint characterizations of  $\Gamma$ and $\Lambda$ obeying the relations. $\Lambda$ should be constrained to be real and diagonal, and non-negativity is a reasonable additional constraint I would be interested in.

Comment: See section 4.6 in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3477) for context, and the bottom of page 54 for an iterative algorithm generating multiple sets of the above matrices, obeying the relations. The paper is from quantum mechanics, so it's probably hard to jump right in; the above problem is a condensed and simplified version of the central mathemical issue. I want to be able to pick matrices guaranteed to obey the constraints without running the algorithm.

Comment: Do you have any restriction on the $\Lambda_i$ apart from being symmetric (wlog on can always assume both to be diagonal after base change)? In particular: Do you want them to be non-degenerate or even positive definite?

Comment: @JohannesHahn ideally, they would be both non-degenerate and positive definite.